# Ionic 2 - receive push notifications

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented push notifications in my app, and I can send notifications from the firebase console.

When I send a notification, the notification is sent but:

1. There is no sound
2. No vibration
3. no led color

Vibration works only when the app is already opened and the screen is up.

```
push.on('notification', (data) => {
            Vibration.vibrate(500);
            NativeAudio.play('mySound');
            //this.navCtrl.push(MyPage);
            console.log("Push notification clicked");
        });
```

How I can trigger sound, vibration, led color when user receive a new push notification? I can control those attributes in my server or there's anything I'm missing on my client?

*Currently testing in Android

Comment: +1, a month ago this worked perfeclty fine (even without the vibrate option, it would vibrate automatically) But it seems like they've updated the sdk/library without yet updating the docs (or something of that matter)

Comment: So downgrade for now ?

Comment: yes, as per new update in push plugin it will vibrate only when app is in foreground.
You can use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/vibration/ when push notification receive.